# Unable to check Checkbox

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to check the checkbox but i am getting following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such 
element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//mat- 
checkbox[@id='mat-checkbox-1']/label/div"}
```

I tried selecting using id, css-selector and xpath but keep on getting error.

```
reg_date_checkbox = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//matcheckbox[@id='mat-checkbox-1']/label/div")
reg_date_checkbox.location_once_scrolled_into_view
reg_date_checkbox.click()
```

The HTML of checkbox is

```
<div _ngcontent-fep-c23="" class="last-date my-12 ng-star-inserted" fxlayout="column" style="flex-direction: column; box-sizing: border-box; display: flex;">
<mat-checkbox _ngcontent-fep-c23="" class="mat-checkbox mat-accent ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" formcontrolname="deadline_enabled" id="mat-checkbox-1">
    <label class="mat-checkbox-layout" for="mat-checkbox-1-input">
        <div class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">
            <input class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="mat-checkbox-1-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false">
            <div class="mat-checkbox-ripple mat-ripple" matripple="">
                <div class="mat-ripple-element mat-checkbox-persistent-ripple"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="mat-checkbox-frame"></div>
            <div class="mat-checkbox-background">
                <svg xml:space="preserve" class="mat-checkbox-checkmark" focusable="false" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path class="mat-checkbox-checkmark-path" d="M4.1,12.7 9,17.6 20.3,6.3" fill="none" stroke="white"></path>
                </svg>
                <div class="mat-checkbox-mixedmark"></div>
            </div>
        </div><span class="mat-checkbox-label"><span style="display:none">&nbsp;</span>The event has a registration deadline</span>
    </label>
</mat-checkbox>
<!---->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to click on the element which is NOT of type 'checkbox'. I see there is an input with type checkbox. Please try below mentioned code

```
reg_date_checkbox = self.browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='mat-checkbox-1-input']")
reg_date_checkbox.click()
```

Additionally if you wish you perform uncheck you can look for input element's aria-checked property to be true before performing a click.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this xpath `//matcheckbox[@id='mat-checkbox-1']/label/div` , it should be `//mat-checkbox[@id='mat-checkbox-1']/label/div` , there's a `-` in between, you are missing that.

Still you can try with this **css selector** :

```
div.mat-checkbox-inner-container input[class^='mat-checkbox-input'][id^='mat-checkbox']
```

There may be chances that the checkbox is in iframe, if it is the case then first switch to frame and then try to click on check box.

Comment: i am getting the following error   selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input class="mat-checkbox-input cdk-visually-hidden" type="checkbox" id="mat-checkbox-2-input" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"> is not clickable at point (421, 64). Other element would receive the click: <div class="mat-checkbox-inner-container">...</div>

Comment: When you do it manually, do you scroll down or do you use any kind of action to interact with element.

Comment: Ok, Can you try with actions class ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
element = self.browser.find_element_by_css("input#mat-checkbox-1-input")
element.click()
```